# Save pdf file from html form on live server

Tags: java, php, html, pdf, server

I have a simple html file that contain input and send button. is there a way to that, when the user submits, puts the data into a PDF file and sends/saves it on live server ? i use [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library but it save pdf on client side.

Answer (score 1):

Common approach is rather to send to the server request from html form than to form pdf on the client side.
If the server is java I would recommend iText library to create pdf.